# Xcode 5 iPhone app app store upload error

Tags: ios, xcode

Hi I created a iPhone app for iOS 7 and assigned icon using AppIcon set in Images.xcassets. It works good. I try to upload the build in app store through Application Builder it gave following error.

**icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: AppIcon 40x40**

**icon specified in the info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: AppIcon 60x60**

Even i gave icons 120 x 120, 80 x 80, 58 x 58.

Please help me. If choose iOS 7 as a target device above 3 icons only ask by AppIcon set but while upload gives error.

Comment: Do you have old icon key/value pairs in your info.plist which refer to these images?

Comment: yes i gave value for both Icon files (iOS 5) and Icon files keys. Even give the same error

Comment: @Wain Tanks for reply could you tell me what is the correct way to add icons in xcode5(steps)?

Comment: Do the images still exist? Is this app for iOS 7 only (which other versions are you trying to support)?

Comment: So you want to remove all of the old icon keys from the info.plist

Comment: Yes I removed old keys still problem not fixed

Comment: The error is caused by keys in the info.plist not matching the available files so the keys must still be there (or there is some wierd caching thing going on which requires cleaning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please used the new version of application loader that was included in Xcode 5, not used the old version.

The menu:`[Xcode]-[Open Developer Tool]-[Application Loader].`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the icon with size 40*40 and 60*60 in your application.

Here my info.plist with all icons for all iOS :

[image]

Add all images on your project and with [this website](http://www.makeappicon.com/) you can generate all the icon size with the good name for iOS 6 and iOS 7 from your image 1024*1024.

Comment: Thanks for the website... I think we don't need Icon-60.png as there is no non retina iPhone that runs iOS 7

Comment: Maybe but if you support iOS 6 you need it.

Comment: iOS 6 will use Icon.png... it doesn't hurt keeping it there :)

Answer (score 0):

Your App icons must be under the top level

[image]

Comment: in xcode5 has AppIcon set with in Images.xcassets. How can I use this?I tried above fix not solve the problem.

Comment: Icons don't need to be top level, but they typically are if you create them by dropping them on the Summary page.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the App Icon package and it worked!